# Records are available only for admin in maintenance equipment module in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I used the maintenance equipement module of odoo 10 i created many records but those records were available only for admin, if another user creates a record that record will be availabe for the user and admin !

how can I make all records visible to all users?

Answer (score 0):

That means, Odoo already defined a record rules for `Maintenance Request`. You can find it here, `Settings -> Technical -> Security Record Rules` (make sure you activated developer mode). And search for `Maintenace Requests` in the search box. You can find 2 record rules one for admin and another for non-admin users.

Either you can modify the existing domain rule or clear it.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

There are three ways to achieve this:

1) **Security Record Rules** - as described by [KbiR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4128957/kbir) you can use security record rules. Firstly activate the developer mode in settings and then in Technical/Security Record Rules you can track the view and change the rules so all fields will be visible to all users.

2) **Front end view edit*** - you can activate the developer mode, go to the view and then click the "Edit View" from the developer mode icon (top right corner). You will see the xml:
[image]

Now you can simply erase the "groups" - the field will be visible for everyone, add "invisible="1" " if you want to make a field invisible or change the group to a desired one.

- this is not really recommended option(except for testing). If you leave it like this your changes might disappear after Odoo update(they will be reset to default).

3) **Change using the custom module** - if you changed the field using the hint from point "2" and it is visible you should make a module to keep changes permanent. You would simply inherit the view and update them with desired "groups".

**Example:**

The module [Opportunity on Sales Order Form](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/opportunities_on_so_form/) activate the hidden field using the code:

```
  <field name="opportunity_id" position="replace">
        <field name="opportunity_id"/>
    </field>
```

It is replacing the "opportunity_id" field with "opportunity_id" field without any "groups". The effect is that the field is visible by everyone.

Comment: I know but we all started somewhere. Today you help him, tomorrow he will help someone else